# Increase HTML5 Range Button

Tags: forms, html, range

I am using code that looks like this:

```
<label for="htop">Top: </label><input type="range" name="htop" id="htop" value="0" min="0" max="2" />
```

I would like to add a button that would increase the value of the range by 1 every time it is pressed. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery, you can do this.

```
$('button#increase').click(function(){
    var range = $('input#htop');
    range.attr('max', parseInt(range.attr('max')) + 1);
});
```

assuming that you have a button with the id of `increase`

http://jquery.com/

Comment: I am using jQuery. Where would I add this script. I tried adding it to the header but it did not work.